# NoMethodError in LinksController#new in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, controller

In my application when I try to add `current_user` Devise helper to the `new` action in Controller, I get this error:

```
undefined method `val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x007fe650498200>
```

And highlight this line in my code :

```
@link = current_user.links.build
```

Controller :

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /links
  # GET /links.json
  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  # GET /links/1
  # GET /links/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /links/new
  def new
    @link = current_user.links.build
  end

  # GET /links/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /links
  # POST /links.json
  def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /links/1
  # PATCH/PUT /links/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.update(link_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /links/1
  # DELETE /links/1.json
  def destroy
    @link.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_link
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url)
    end
end
```

Comment: Which rails version are you using? Try upgrading it. If that doesn't help, please add a part of User model where association with Links is defined.

Comment: `before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]` you missed

Comment: In the User model => `has_many :links`  and rails is updated (4.2.0)

Comment: @RajarshiDas i'm add this before_action but still same error :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to add the `foreign_key` `user_id` to the `links` table.

Create a migration to add it link this:

```
$ rails g migration add_user_id_to_links
```

An then in your migration:

```
class AddUserIdToLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :links, :user_id, :integer, null: false
    add_index :links, :user_id
  end
end
```

The error message is not very clear or verbose, but that is something is already corrected in latest Rails version as you can see [in this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/78bd18a90992e3da767cfe492f1bc5d63077da8a).

Comment: Ping! Accepting valid answers is SO etiquette over here ;)

Comment: Great answer @dgilperez. Right on spot. Thanks
I run into some trouble with `null: false`. It generates and SQL error that I fixed by replacing it with `nil: false` since we are dealing with integers